# Finding which item from list was randomly chosen

Tags: python, list

I have a Tkinter program choosing a random game for me to play. I set up the list and need my program to see which game is chosen so that it can launch the game from its file location. What I have doesn't work. Can you tell me how to find which game was chosen?

```
def genRanGame(self):
    game = ['BF4', 'CSGO', 'GTA', 'FC3', 'DB']
    self.game.set(random.choice(game))
    if game == "BF4":
        print ("This is working")
    if game == 'CSGO':
        print ("This is really working")
```

Comment: Did you mean `if self.game == "BF4"`? `game` is still the list. Could you show a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that *actually recreates the issue*? *"doesn't work"* isn't a terribly helpful problem description...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the `random.choice()` result in a variable first:

```
games = ['BF4', 'CSGO', 'GTA', 'FC3', 'DB']
game_picked = random.choice(games)
self.game.set(game_picked)
if game_picked == "BF4":
    # ...
```

or retrieve it from the object you set it on; presumably `self.game` is a Tkinter `StringVar()` object or similar; it has a `.get()` method as well as a `.set()` method, you can use that to read out the random choice you set as well:

```
games = ['BF4', 'CSGO', 'GTA', 'FC3', 'DB']
self.game.set(random.choice(games))
if self.game.get() == "BF4":
    # ...
```

The list object (I named it `games` to better reflect the contents) doesn't change when using `random.choice()`, so `games == 'BF4'` is never going to be true; it is still set to that whole list and not to just one choice from the list.